# Change Flux to Mono<Flux>

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

I use Spring Boot, Webflux and OPENAPI. I want to change `Flux` to `Mono<Flux>` because `Openapi` generated the following method and I want to adjust my code to the method result type:

```
 public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<SecurityData>>> getSecurityByGroupId( //method header generated by openapi
      UUID groupId, String securityType, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return securitySummaryService.getSecurityByGroupId(groupId, protectorType) //returns Flux<SecurityData>
        .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
        .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

}

How to do that?

Currently I have the following error:

Required type: `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<SecurityData>>>`

Provided: `Flux<ResponseEntity<SecurityData>>`

I'd like to avoid Mono.just because then the code compiles without any errors but when `securitySummaryService.getSecurityByGroupId` returns empty value I can't check if my Flux is empty.

```
 public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<SecurityData>>> getSecurityByGroupId( //method header generated by openapi
          UUID groupId, String securityType, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.just(securitySummaryService.getSecurityByGroupId(groupId, protectorType)) 
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

Comment: Probably should fix your OpenApi definition.

Comment: the method generated is just flat out wrong.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's a valuable tip for me